# How to reduce flickering in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using **export QT_ONSCREEN_PAINT=force** while running my executable file. So while updating the values for UI controls , the onscreen paint updates only the controls and not the entire widget.

> Because this effect my controls are flickering while update the values.How to resolve this.

Comment: Don't use QT_ONSCREEN_PAINT ;)

Comment: if i did not use QT_ONSCREEN_PAINT entire widget is not showing in my ECU.

Comment: Anybody knows any other exports to update the entire widgets

Comment: It should work without QT_ONSCREEN_PAINT .. if not, you are doing something wrong. Btw. what do you mean by ECU?

Comment: Why do you want to update the entire widgets? If you use custom widgets with custom paintings and updating doesn’t work correctly, there most probably a problem in your implementation.